# How do I apply Green's theorem to evaluate $\iint_{\Omega} xy\ dxdy$ where $\Omega$ is a triangle in the $z=0$ plane?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, surface-integrals, greens-theorem

I specifically want to know how I can apply Green's Theorem to solve the above when $\Omega$ is an arbitrary triangle in the $z=0$ plane with vertices $\{\mathbf{v}_0,\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\}$ where $\mathbf{v}_i = [v_{i,x}, v_{i,y}]$.

Comment: The exact location of the triangle matters because $xy$ isn't exactly a location agnostic (i.e. translation invariant) function. Is one provided?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks for your response! I have edited my original post in response to your comment.

Comment: To use Green's theorem to convert a double integral to a line integral, you need a "vector potential" of $xy$, which means you need functions $P(x,y),Q(x,y)$ such that $Q_x-P_y=xy$. Of course there is more than one way to do this; for example you could take $Q=x^2 y/2,P=0$. Then you just have to do the line integral around the triangle, which is indeed going to depend explicitly on the coordinates of the vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Green's Theorem in the Plane:**
>
> Let $\Omega$ be a closed, bounded domain in the $(x,y)$ plane with piecewise smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. Then $$\iint_\Omega \bigg(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial q}{\partial y}\bigg) \, dx dy = \oint _{\partial \Omega} (p,q) \cdot \mathbf n \, ds$$ where $\partial \Omega$ is positively-oriented, and $\mathbf n$ is the outward unit normal to $\partial \Omega$.

In your case, $\Omega$ is the triangular domain, and $\partial \Omega$ the edges of the triangle.

Let $\partial \Omega = C_1 \cup C_2 \cup C_3$ where $C_1, C_2,C_3$ are the three edges (oriented counter-clockwise) with corresponding outward unit normals $\mathbf n_1, \mathbf n_2, \mathbf n_3$. We then have

$$\iint_\Omega xy \, dxdy = \iint_\Omega \bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac 12 x^2y\bigg) + \frac {\partial}{\partial y}(0)\bigg] \,dxdy = \sum_{i=1}^3 \int_{C_i}\bigg(\frac12 x^2y \, , \, 0\bigg) \cdot \mathbf n_i \, ds$$

and it is then a matter of finding $\mathbf n_i$ for each edge and parameterising each edge, then computing the integrals.

Comment: Interesting that you call the divergence version "Green's theorem". I'm used to calling the curl version Green's theorem, and calling the divergence version a corollary (obtained by rotating the field and the tangent both clockwise by 90 degrees).